# Converting .sav file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, spss, rpy2

I'm in the process of writing a data checker to review spss files and need to programmatically handle different checks. The first step is to access an spss file, convert it to a pandas dataframe and run my checks from there. The only way I've found to do this is through RPY2. I know very little R unfortunately and can't get either solution below to work. Any help/literature would be much appreciated.

I've pulled some stuff from other posts and created this:

#### Using RPY2

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import r
from pathlib import Path
import pyreadstat
pandas2ri.activate()

w = r('foreign::read.spss("%s", to.data.frame=TRUE)' % filename)
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(w)
df.head()
w.head()
```

#### Error:

```
rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded.RRuntimeError: Error in foreign::read.spss("path to test.sav",  : 
  error reading system-file header
```

#### Using pyreadstat (this gives me the columns, but errors out when I attempt to get the underlying data)

```
    meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(filename, metadataonly=True)
    cols = [x for x in meta[0]]
    df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav(filename, usecols=cols)
    print(df)
```

#### Error:

```
pyreadstat._readstat_parser.PyreadstatError: STRING type with value 4/23/19 17:50 with date type
```

## UPDATE:

Using haven now but still getting errors:

```
rdf = r(f'haven::read_sav("{filename}")')
```

#### Error:

`ValueError: Invalid value NaN (not a number)`

Comment: For pyreadstat please submit an issue in the github repo WITH an example file. Those formatting errors you are describing are known and just need an example file for the C library to learn how to parse them correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I did it using pyreadstat, your second option:

```
df, metadata = pyreadstat.read_sav("path to file", metadataonly=True)
```

This returns an empty DF (only column´s names) and all the metadata.
With `metadata.variable_value_labels` you get a dictionary with the values of the variables.

```
df, metadata = pyreadstat.read_sav("path to file", apply_value_formats=True)
```

This will return the DF with all the values already replaced.

This may help https://ofajardo.github.io/pyreadstat_documentation/_build/html/index.html

Answer (score 3):

To build off/update DiegoC's answer on `pyreadstat`, you can use `pd.read_spss` if you have `pyreadstat` installed. So, it's as easy as:

```
df = pd.read_spss("path_to_sav_file.sav")
```

Again, you need `pyreadstat` to use `pd.read_spss` so if an error pops up telling you to install `pyreadstat`, go ahead and do what it tells you. For the ultra noobers:

```
$ pip install pyreadstat
```

or

```
$ conda install pyreadstat
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather you can use scipy.io.readsav library to convert the `.sav` file to a dictionary

```
scipy.io.readsav(file_name, idict=None, python_dict=False,
 uncompressed_file_name=None, verbose=False)
```

Then the dictionary can be easily converted into a pandas dataframe.

Comment: scipy.io.readsav is to read an IDL file, not a SPSS file

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [SavReaderWriter package](https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/):

```
pip install savReaderWriter --upgrade

import pandas
import savReaderWriter

with savReaderWriter.SavReader('mydata.sav', ioUtf8 = True) as reader:
    df = pandas.DataFrame(reader.all(), columns = [s.decode('CP1252') for s in reader.header])
df.head()
```